# Exclude specific method/constructor from Android JUnit test coverage using Robolectric

Tags: java, android, junit, test-coverage

I'm currently doing a whole new project and writing some utilities such as `StringUtil.java`.

I have a private constructor like below.

```java
public class StringUtil {

  // TODO Exclude this from measuring test coverage
  private StringUtil() { }

  public static boolean isEqual(String a, String b){
     return true;
  }     
}
```

After doing `Run test... with Coverage` in android studio, I got my coverage which is not 100%. Because the private Constructor is not called.

Is there any workaround to exclude private constructor from measuring test coverage(without calling it, indeed)?

Comment: ["Dont' let the tool be in charge of you"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4520241/2754160)

Comment: @h.j.k. Thanks for the valuable opinion. Still it seems little bit controversial though. I'll have a conversation with my team as well. Thanks again.