# The Sonar way to define a constant

Tags: java, sonarqube

I use Sonarqube 5.1 and experiment with the “Sonar way” Java quality profile. The job is simple: I want to define a *global* String constant for a missing media type:

```
public interface Utf8MediaType {
    String APPLICATION_JSON = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
}
```

However, Sonarqube tells me this is bad practice in rule *squid:S1214 – Constants should not be defined in interfaces*. The long text talks about implementing this interface, which I didn’t intend to, but I give in and create a class instead:

```
public class Utf8MediaType {
    public static final String APPLICATION_JSON = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
}
```

However, this is considered to be a major design issue in rule *squid:S1118 – Utility classes should not have public constructors*. So it’s urging me to add a private constructor. Of course, this constructor has then to come first not to violate conventions in rule *squid:S1213 – The members of an interface declaration or class should appear in a pre-defined order*. I guess after that I might even get *common-java:InsufficientBranchCoverage* because the private constructor is not covered in tests.

---

These are the default rules and I feel they are a bit silly in combination. I have more examples where the defaults just don’t work for us (TestNG support is lacking).
What can I do about it? What do you recommend?

- Give in. Make it a class, add a private constructor, use introspection in the unit test. Makes the code ten times as big. For a String constant.
- Create a list of exceptions. But doing this for each project may lead to long lists and invites people to add exceptions even for important stuff.
- Deactivate rules. Now I would prefer *not* to tamper with the default profiles, because that may mean a lot of work on Sonarqube upgrades.
- Create a profile that inherits from the default and overwrites things. It turns out that when you inherit from a profile you cannot *deactivate* rules. You can only add additional rules and change the configuration of rules (to lower their severity).

Comment: "you cannot deactivate rules" <-- are you sure about that?

Comment: Well, @fge, if I knew how to do it, I’d do it. That would be my personal preference.

Comment: Log in as admin, click on the Rules tab, select the profile that you use, find the rule and click the "deactivate" button...

Comment: There is no ‘deactivate’ button in my version of Sonarqube. Be aware that I referred to profiles _inheriting_ from another profile. When I have a profile ‘My way’ inheriting from ‘Sonar way’, then that button is only on the ‘Sonar way’ line for a rule.

Comment: What about using an ENUM for all your media types? as your media types grows/changes, you can easily adjust your class for it?

Comment: The media types are used as values for certain annotations. Therefore they have to be strings, and they have to be compile-time constants.

Comment: As a fan of brevity, I prefer `interface` as it makes `public static final` obsolete on all the lines. I don't see the risk of somebody wanting to implement your `Utf8MediaType` interface for example. Sonarlint certainly has not my support on that rule :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Give in. Make it a class, add a private constructor, use introspection in the unit test. Makes the code ten times as big. For a String constant.

This is the correct approach in general.  You really do not want to create a "Constants" interface.  The private constructor is needed to ensure that users do not inadvertently extend or instantiate an object that should not be instantiated.

[How to add test coverage to a private constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520216/how-to-add-test-coverage-to-a-private-constructor/10872497#10872497)

> Create a list of exceptions. But doing this for each project may lead to long lists and invites people to add exceptions even for important stuff.

Too much work.

> Deactivate rules. Now I would prefer not to tamper with the default profiles, because that may mean a lot of work on Sonarqube upgrades.

As you said... bad idea.

> Create a profile that inherits from the default and overwrites things. It turns out that when you inherit from a profile you cannot deactivate rules. You can only add additional rules and change the configuration of rules (to lower their severity).

If you set the severity to "info" it will remove it from the Technical Debt calculation.  I had to do that with `squid:S1213` which is raised when I sort using the default order specified by Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a few years since this was asked but sonarlint is still complaining about

```
public interface Utf8MediaType {
    String APPLICATION_JSON = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
}
```

and now sonarlint proposes

```
public final class Utf8MediaType {
    public static final String APPLICATION_JSON = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
}
```

but I still dislike these "extra" `public static final` that I don't need when using an `interface`. In our project we transition to Kotlin which can be done on a file by file basis and there the way to go is:

```
object Utf8MediaType {
    const val APPLICATION_JSON = "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
}
```

which is even shorter than a Java interface.

Comment: Though that doesn’t solve my Java problem at all, you get a big _YES_ from me for using Kotlin. I just have to wait a little bit longer until my employer officially allows it as a Java alternative.

Comment: I must say as an Android developer I'm getting massively deceived by Google. Java11 is much more like Kotlin than Java8 what we are stuck with on Android. If you are on Android though, there is no reason not to move to Kotlin. It's the official way to go according to Google.