# How to add test coverage to a private constructor in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, testing, constructor

I've found solutions in Java but none in Kotlin.
Some idea where to see some examples?

Java example here: [How to add test coverage to a private constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520216/how-to-add-test-coverage-to-a-private-constructor)

Comment: What's your goal with this? Test coverage shouldn't be a goal in itself. Do you intend to actually test this constructor?

Answer (score 1):

If your private constructor cannot be called from any public API, you should just delete it. If it is of any use, there should be a way to call it through other public APIs. This is the path that your tests should cover.

For instance, if the private constructor is called from a factory function in the companion object, then use that factory function in your test.

In Java, some private constructors were not reachable through public APIs because they were used in classes that had only static members (their role was to prevent instantiation of such classes, which is pointless). This created noise in test coverage. But in Kotlin, the same functionality can be achieved using `object`s instead of classes, and you don't have to declare any private constructors there, which eliminates the need to add coverage for it altogether.